# Can Property Let/Get be called dynamically or does each Property need its own function?

Tags: excel, vba, class, properties

I have an Excel VBA class with approximately 30 different Properties.

I want to avoid writing a Get/Let function for each of them.

Is there any way to dynamically pass the Property and value?

Pseudo code would look something like:

```
Private strID As String
Private dblAmt As Double
Private dtMatDate As Date

Property Get PropertyName(arg1)
    [get value for whatever Property arg1 represents]
End Property

Property Let PropertyName(arg1,arg2)
    [set value for Property arg1 to value of arg2]
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were to collect all of the private properties into a private collection using a Key at Initialization, then you could use the Key to access the value of the private property. Be advised that you are weakening your typing and there is no real way to ensure that you pass the proper arg1 string to get a member of the collection with this approach. YMMV

```
Private strID As String
Private dblAmt As Double
Private dtMatDate As Date
Private myProperties As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set myProperties = New Collection
    With myProperties
        .Add strID, "ID"
        .Add dblAmt, Key:="Amount"
        .Add dtMatDate, Key:="MatDate"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set myProperties = Nothing
End Sub
Property Get PropertyValue(ByVal arg1 As String) As Variant
    PropertyValue = myProperties(arg1)
End Property

Property Let PropertyValue(ByVal arg1 As String, ByVal arg2 As Variant)
    myProperties(arg1) = arg2
End Property
```